# after upgrading new version Xcode/swift error Ambiguous of subscript

Tags: xcode, swift

after upgrading to new version of Xcode/swift i am getting error "Ambiguous use of subscript before was work well but now i am getting this error

my code for search in my data

```
    @IBAction func searchB(sender: UITextField) {

dataSecond = []
if sender.text == "" {
search = false
    self.reload()

} else {
for i in data {
if (i["name"] as! String!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) { //Here is the error in this if condition
dataSecond.addObject(i)
}
}
search = true
    self.reload()

}
```

Comment: `dataSecond` is Array or Dictionary?

Comment: NSMutableArray  Array

Comment: And how you are adding data?

Comment: i updated my code please see it

Comment: Just assign the var dataSecond = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>()

Comment: i did i get same error and another error in     dataSecond.addObject(i) Value of type Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
has no member addObject ;(

Comment: Now you need to do: dataSecond.append(i)

Comment: still i get same old error i added what you said     if (i["name"] as! String!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) {
    dataSecond.append(i as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)

Comment: i get error Ambiguous of subscript in line     if (i["name"] as! String!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) {

Comment: The problem is you are directly accessing the `Dictionary` but you need access like `array[index]["name"]`

Comment: please tell me how i do it

Comment: First let me know what type of data you are getting?

Comment: json by php you can see link http://www.arabfono.com/show22.php for sample this same i use but in this link you will see "title" in my original link i use "name"

Comment: Fine let me check I will be back in few minutes

Comment: ok my dear i am waiting you

Comment: I hope you json is wrong, because it must starts with `NSDictionary` and your's is starting with an `Array`

Comment: its was work fine after yesterday upgraded Xcode i got this error

Comment: The error is because, you have not given the specific type to your variable.

Comment: so what i can do now :(

Comment: i think i need to add something in this line with string     if (i["name"] as! String!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) {

Comment: Just try out with this - `if (i[0]["name"] as! String!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) `

Comment: i will try i will back after 2 hour and tell u what happen with me

Comment: still see same error

Comment: thanks for your help i was fix it just i change string to ! then fixed

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 is rather strict about types, much more strict than the previous versions. What was implicit before has now to be explicit.

Use safe unwrapping and downcasting and it should work:

```
if let senderText = sender.text {
    for i in data {
        if let name = i["name"] as? String {
            if name.lowercaseString.findInString(senderText) {
                dataSecond.addObject(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get error in same line      if let name = i["name"] as? String {
Ambiguous of subscript

Comment: Then it means that `i` itself is of unknown type, the compiler doesn't know it's a dictionary. You have to cast `i` as an NSDictionary or to cast `data` as an array of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks for your replay i fixed by just i change string with !    if (i["name"]!).lowercaseString.findInString(sender.text!) {